# Erro Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, regex

Boa tarde galera do stackoverflow.
Tem como saber se existe alguma data em um array??
Vinha tentando, usando da seguinte forma:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
        if(preg_match( "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$" , $array[$i] )){
            echo 'true';
        }else{
            echo 'false';
        }
    }
```

Só que vem apresentando erros:

> Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\ecoprintQ\ecoLicenseLayout\json\dados-partners-r‌​epots.php on line 14

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Que **erros**? Erro de `parse`? Retorna algo como `true` que não deveria? Seja mais claro por favor.

Comment: Dá uma exemplo de algum valor que falha e outro que deve passar.

Comment: Deve falhar, uma string qualquer "Ola mundo", "Cadastro aprovado", passar: "22/02/2017"
Qualquer data

Me retorna isso

**Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\ecoprintQ\ecoLicenseLayout\json\dados-partners-repots.php on line <i>14**

Comment: Faltou colocar os delimitadores na regex, deixe assim: `preg_match( "#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$#"`

Comment: Basicamente é erro de sintaxe na RegEx, atualizei as tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta os delimitadores, as funções `preg` exigem isto e talvez também falte o `^` na regex `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$`, faça assim `#^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$#`:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if(preg_match( "#^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$#" , $array[$i] )){
        echo 'true';
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Entenda o que são os delimitadores e como eles funcionam no PCRE: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '#' found in

Comment: bem, valeu, deu certo

Comment: @gabrielfalieri blz, que bom!